# Slow load / database access times on Google App Engine and Cloud SQL

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm using Google Cloud Services for my business.  Our platform is based on PHP and mySQL, and I use App Engine and Cloud SQL for this.  I'm using default App Engine scaling settings with F1 instance and a D2 Cloud SQL instance (because of speed issues).  Once I switched from a shared hosting plan to Google, my website has drastically slowed down in performance.  Saving settings takes up to 13 seconds sometimes - and now I'm paying $350 a month instead of $20.

Am I doing something wrong?  How can I either reduce costs dramatically or increase performance so the huge price hike is worth it?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/support/

Comment: I don't want to pay $150 for email support - Google's "community forums" just link to Stack Overflow, which is why I asked the question here

Comment: Well, you're paying $350, so $150 might be a bargain if they fix your issue.

Comment: True - I'll wait and see if anyone here has suggestions first though

Comment: And it looks like I'd need to get the "Gold" plan ($400) in order to ask a question about something other than a bug / fix ticket - my problem is larger than that.

Comment: Set your `Activation Policy` on the `Cloud SQL` instance settings to be `Always On`, this way, the `MySQL` service will not be shut down when not in use. Also, make sure that you are collocating your `Cloud SQL` instance with your `App Engine` application, that is under `Location preference` on the `Edit Instance` page.

Comment: We couldn't use Cloud SQL in production due to terrible performance. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54503324/1290457